# how get branch in another local branch

Tags: git, github

I create `feature_test` local branch .

Then edit my code and commit and push to `origin feature_test` .

But not yet approve my pull request .

Now i want get this commit and edit and push in another local .

How create new branch and get changes and work on then push on previous pull request ?

Comment: You shouldn't do more work on top of unapproved work, what if it doesn't get approved?

Comment: I work in another system . and push . but not yet approved . now i in other system and i want those changes

Answer (score 1):

if I am understanding your question correctly, this is what I would do:

**Assumption: your head at the currect branch is pointing to the commit that you pushed to origin**

I will make sure that i am on `feature_test` first by doing:

```
git checkout feature_test
```

then I will branch out off `feature_test` by doing:

```
git checkout -b feature_test_2
```

then I will work on this branch and commit my changes (need not track it remotely)

after i am done, I can switch back to `feature_test` and merge changes from `feature_test_2`by doing:

```
git checkout feature_test
git merge feature_test_2
```

now I can just push my changes and they will appear on the same pull request. so, just do a:

```
git push
```

Comment: `feature_test` is in other local . in other local push to `origin/featre_test` . now in another system i do not now how create local branch and get code from `origin/feature_test`

Comment: have you committed your code in other local ? if not, just execute `git checkout -b feature_test_2` and then commit on `feature_test_2`. now comeback to `feature_test` and execute `git pull` then merge `feature_test_2` to `feature_test` locally.

Comment: another branch commited and push . but until pull request not approved

Comment: well I am asking about the changes that you were working on currently.

Answer (score 1):

I take "I work in another system and i want those changes" that you are now working on a different machine and you want to edit the tree named 'feature_test'?

If so you can simply do:

```
$ git clone <repo>
$ cd <repo>
// Checkout your 'feature_test' branch
$ git checkout feature_test
Branch 'feature_test' set up to track remote branch 'feature_test' from 
'origin'. Switched to a new branch 'feature_test'
```

You now have a local branch that tracks the 'origin/feature_test'.  You can now make changes locally and then push them to origin to update 'origin/feature_test'.

```
$ echo foo > foo_file
$ git add foo_file
$ git commit -m "Foo commit msg"
$ git push origin
```

Comment: Mostafa Norzade is that what you are searching for?  Let me know if I misunderstood your situation.